# Charging my 4V battery with a lab bench power supply isn't working, any ideas why? The battery voltage decreases

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-charging

I'm charging a 4V GAMA-SONIC RB420E 2.0AH Lead Acid battery.
Standby use 4.5V.
Max charging current 0.6A, I used 0.5A just to be on the safe side.
For some reason the battery voltage isn't increasing but instead decreasing, the power supply is a MCH303A power supply, 30V 3A.

Comment: What open circuit voltage is your lab supply set to?

Comment: 4.5V, and 0.6A in the curent limit

Comment: Hint: I sometimes charge my car 12 V battery, which has 6 cells in series) with a supply I made which has an **open load voltage** (nothing is connected) of 13.8 V. You can calculate how much that is per cell. Then multiply by the number of cells you have. That's the open load voltage to which you need to set your supply. That means 4.6 V, close to the 4.5 V you have. Did you consider that your battery is already fully charged? What is the "no load" voltage of the battery?

Comment: One possibility is that the battery is a goner.

Comment: The battery's voltage at no load is 2.37

Comment: Then one cell is already dead. Unless you meant 2.37V per cell, in which case it should start to charge at 4.8V, 4.5V is not enough.

Comment: No, it's 2.37V from the terminals, do you need a picture?

Comment: So what do I do? Just throw it to the trash?

Comment: Recycle it......

Comment: :( you know what I meant. Do I need to throw it or I can somehow use it?

Comment: No, you can't use it anymore, the battery voltage has dropped too low and that damaged it. So it needs to be recycled. Lead Acid batteries contain **lead** so the battery should not be treated as normal waste. Therefore it needs to be recycled so that the lead can be extracted and re-used.

Comment: You should be able to recycle it at an auto parts store--anywhere that deals in car batteries is going to know how to properly recycle lead-acid batteries. I've never had to recycle one myself, but that's where I would look first at least.